# Filtering based on a text column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

Is doing an exact match filter based on a text column conceptually slower than grabbing a set of rows based on a key and filtering using the programming language?

For example:

```
select columns from table where textcolumn='exactphrase';
```

vs

```
select columns from table where key='key';

for (results : resultset) { 
      if (resulsts.getString(textcolumn).equals(exactphrase)) { ... } }
```

I'm basically curious as to how MySQL (Innodb) deals with filtering text columns and what the performance pitfalls may be (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; **There will be no performance difference for "finding" the record.**

Since the (indexed) PK is being used then *at most* a single record will be returned. The server is smart enough to *not* perform a table scan on the text column, even if it is not indexed because of the 1-1 cardinality of the PK. (Query planners are smart.)

The differences are then:

1. The server might return a "useless" record to the client; this may waste a small amount of bandwidth<sup>1</sup> (and slightly more wasteful if the text isn't required except for the test anyway), but more importantly it *muddles semantics* of the query.
2. The server supports different *collation* modes; it might therefor be *case insensitive* (e.g.) on the server and result in slightly different results than a client side filter.

---

<sup>1</sup> While very degenerate cases can be imagined, this should be take as "equivalent time" without an explicit use/performance case. It is, however, IMOHO, still sloppy to do this on the client side without further reason.

Comment: sorry, i updated my post. i appreciate the explanation, but i accidentally kept writing primary key when i really just meant an indexed column.

Comment: @tau Again, modern query planners are smart. They will almost always favor indices over table scans, depending upon statistics. Ask for the *specific* query plan used if there are doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, but I doubt it.

Within a set of constraints every single table, database and query is different. How "quick" a query is, on a single server, can depend on the following (among many other things):

- Indexes
- The cardinality of the column - how many distinct values there are vs the number of values.
- The width of the column
- The number of records in the table
- The number of bytes being returned in the query.
- Whether anyone else is using the database / server

Generally speaking it's always quicker to do everything in SQL, but this does depend on all of the above so it is by no means certain.

The only way to be sure is to try it yourself. If you then have problems you can always post your query, the explain plans and the table and index definitions and maybe someone will be able to help.